# How can I find next available value in a table in the fastest way

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains a varchar column which is indexed. The values in this column consist of a prefix and an incrementing number value. It is not necessary the values will be in order.

```
ABC00010
ABC00011
ABC00015
ABC00012
ABC00017
ABC00016
and so on...
```

There may be missing values in the sequence. How can I find the smallest number available for insert?

I wrote this and it works. But it takes a few seconds when the numbers are in the thousands.

```
Declare @C int = 1;
While Exists(Select 1 From MyTable Where Col='ABC'+Format(@C,'00000')) Set @C=@C+1;
Select 'Next Number: ABC'+Format(@C,'00000');
```

Is there a faster way?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Where do I create this?

Comment: One option: https://dbfiddle.uk/-SXv3GHO

Comment: *Is there a faster way?* Yes absolutely - Fix your design - if your table was in at least 1NF you would not need to mess around with splitting strings or loops; a column should *always* contain a single atomic value.

Comment: In SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/pHjqfOfO

Comment: @Stu, I fully agree. However, the actual use-case is a fairly complex and involves user-generated prefixes and a numbering system that may change on the fly.

Comment: @navigator then I would consider using some indexed computed columns which would allow the optimizer to properly aggregate and seek to the appropriate row and a set-based query will run in milliseconds.

Comment: [Dupe on DBA.StackExchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/320081/150011). Please don't cross-post.

Comment: Removed from DBA

Answer (score 2):

Always think set-based operations. A While loop is not set-based. Here I create a CTE with sequential numbers from 0 through 99999. Then I match the sequence CTE to the "MyTable", order the list, and select a `TOP 1` from a `RIGHT JOIN`.

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE (
    Col nvarchar(8)
);

INSERT INTO @myTable
VALUES ('ABC00001'), ('ABC00002'), ('ABC00005'), ('ABC00003')
;

WITH x AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) v(n))
, y as (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as number
    FROM x ones, x tens, x hundreds, x thousands, x tThousands
)
, yMod as (
    SELECT y.number
        , 'ABC' + RIGHT('00000' + CAST(y.number as nvarchar), 5) as Col
    FROM y 
)
SELECT TOP 1
    ym.Col
FROM @myTable as mt
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN yMod as ym
        ON ym.Col = mt.Col
WHERE mt.Col IS NULL
ORDER BY ym.number
```

Comment: This is very interesting. I was trying to think of a set based approach but couldn't. My actual use-case is a bit more complex. But let me see if I can use this approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could adopt a Gaps-and-Islands approach.

The following are two approaches.   The first will show just the next available value which the second will show all ranges

Made a quick modification to allow a variable Prefix  ... `@Prefix`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Col] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('ABC00010')
,('ABC00011')
,('ABC00015')
,('ABC00012')
,('ABC00017')
,('ABC00016')

Declare @Prefix varchar(25)='ABC'

-- Show Just the Next Value
Select distinct NextValue = min(@Prefix+right(concat('00000',try_convert(int,substring(max(Col),len(@Prefix)+1,25))+1),5)) over()
 From  (
        Select *
              ,Grp = try_convert(int,substring(Col,len(@Prefix)+1,25)) -row_number() over(order by Col)
         From @YourTable
         Where Col like @Prefix+'%'
       ) A     
 Group By Grp



-- Show All Next Values 
Select R1=min(Col)
      ,R2=max(Col)
      ,NextValue = left(max(Col),3)+right(concat('00000',try_convert(int,substring(max(Col),len(@Prefix)+1,25))+1),5)
 From  (
        Select *
              ,Grp = try_convert(int,substring(Col,len(@Prefix)+1,25)) -row_number() over(order by Col)
         From @YourTable
         Where Col like @Prefix+'%'
       ) A     
 Group By Grp
```

**Results**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
Declare @testData table (Col varchar(20));
 Insert Into @testData (Col)
 Values ('ABC00001'), ('ABC00002'), ('ABC00012'), ('ABC00013')
      , ('XYZ00002'), ('XYZ00003'), ('XYZ00010'), ('XYX00012');

Declare @prefix char(3) = 'XYZ';

   With gaps
     As (
 Select *
      , grp = v.inc - row_number() Over(Order By v.inc)
   From @testData As td
  Cross Apply (Values (replace(td.Col, @prefix, ''))) As v(inc)
  Where td.Col Like @prefix + '%'
        )
 Select Top 1
        next_value = concat(@prefix, right(concat('00000', max(g.inc) + 1), 5))
   From gaps As g
  Group By
        g.grp
  Order By
        next_value;
```

Explanation:

1. td.Col Like @prefix + '%': get only those that match
2. Use CROSS APPLY to return just the numeric portion of the string.
3. Use that value minus the row_number value to define each group.
4. Get the max inc (number) + 1 as the next available number for each group
5. Concat the prefix and zeroes to reform the next column value
6. Get the TOP 1 (first) available next value

Comment: Can you explain what you are doing?

Comment: @navigator - this is a typical gaps & islands problem.  In the CTE we define each 'group' of integers, which we get by parsing out the string portion of the column.  Once we have each group - we can then get the max value + 1 for that integer and recombine them to form the 'next' available for that group.  Then a simple TOP 1 to get the first value.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment from the dupe post that was on DBA.StackExchange:

> It's for a specific prefix among other conditions on the table as well. Prefixes are always the same length.

That makes this a much simpler problem to solve, with some CTE *magic*. First filter the table with a starts-with `WHERE` clause for the prefix you care about, then use the `SUBSTRING()` function to trim out the prefix and order by the remaining numbers of the value. Finally, you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to find where the numerical value of the row doesn't match its ordinal, when sorted by that numerical value.

Example below:

```
WITH _ColNumbers AS
(
    SELECT
        CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(Col, 4, LEN(Col) - 3)) AS ColNumber, -- Strip out the prefix and convert the remaining numerical part to an integer 
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE Col LIKE 'ABC%'
),
_ColNumbersSorted AS
(
    SELECT 
        ColNumber,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ColNumber) AS SortId -- Generate a sequential set of integers in the same order as ColNumber
    FROM _ColNumbers
),
_ColNumberLowestUnmatchedSortId AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1 -- Return the single lowest mismatch
        ColNumber,
        SortId
    FROM _ColNumbersSorted
    WHERE ColNumber <> SortId -- Filter down to only the rows that don't match their ColNumber to their SortId
    ORDER BY SortId -- Sort by the lowest SortId (aka lowest mismatch)
)

-- Join back to the list of all ColNumbers to get the row just before the lowest mismatch
-- The lowest available number is 1 more than the previous row's ColNumber
SELECT 
    CNS.ColNumber + 1 AS LowestAvailableNumber 
FROM _ColNumbersSorted AS CNS
INNER JOIN _ColNumberLowestUnmatchedSortId AS CNLUSI
    ON CNS.SortId = CNLUSI.SortId - 1;
```

At a quick glance, this may appear like a lot, but each CTE just represents each logical step for better readability. The performance should be pretty good, though one thing that could help performance is adding a computed column for `CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(Col, 4, LEN(Col) - 3))` and creating an index on it, such that the calculation is already persisted (because it's not a [SARGable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/799584/5059085) expression). You can achieve that with the following code:

```
ALTER MyTable
ADD CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(Col, 4, LEN(Col) - 3)) AS ColNumber;

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_MyTable_Col_ColNumber ON MyTable (Col, ColNumber);
```

Not only would that help performance, doing so simplifies the code a little bit like so:

```
WITH _ColNumbersSorted AS
(
    SELECT 
        ColNumber,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ColNumber) AS SortId -- Generate a sequential set of integers in the same order as ColNumber
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE Col LIKE 'ABC%'
),
_ColNumberLowestUnmatchedSortId AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1 -- Return the single lowest mismatch
        ColNumber,
        SortId
    FROM _ColNumbersSorted
    WHERE ColNumber <> SortId -- Filter down to only the rows that don't match their ColNumber to their SortId
    ORDER BY SortId -- Sort by the lowest SortId (aka lowest mismatch)
)

-- Join back to the list of all ColNumbers to get the row just before the lowest mismatch
-- The lowest available number is 1 more than the previous row's ColNumber
SELECT 
    CNS.ColNumber + 1 AS LowestAvailableNumber 
FROM _ColNumbersSorted AS CNS
INNER JOIN _ColNumberLowestUnmatchedSortId AS CNLUSI
    ON CNS.SortId = CNLUSI.SortId - 1;
```

Comment: Thanks. We did manage to solve the issue with a similar approach.

Comment: @navigator Cool, make sure you verify the performance is sufficient. I can see a couple of places in the solution that would be needed for this kind of problem, where the performance can go south if the query isn't tuned properly.

Answer (score 0):

A better option would be to not delete records but mark them as deleted. Use a  BIT column as "deleted" flag for this. Then you can easily select the smallest deleted record and re-use it.

If no one was found, select the largest one and add 1 to the index. Or, even better, use a [sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sequence-numbers/sequence-numbers?view=sql-server-ver16) to generate indexes.

```sql
-- delete
UPDATE mytable SET deleted = 1 WHERE id = @id;
```

```sql
-- find record to be reused.
SELECT MIN(Col) FROM mytable WHERE deleted = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, but the rows are not actually deleted. They are just with a different 'Status' column. Furthermore, there are several other elements in the where clause to determine the next sequence number.